# Individual with "null" object property

Tags: ontology, protege, assertion

I am working on an ontology task in `Protege`.

**Situation:** I have `Student class` that has subclasses of `InactiveStudent`, `ActiveStudent` and `VeryActiveStudent`. These subclasses have conditions related to object property called `isEnrolledForSubject`. I defined conditions for:

```
ActiveStudent = 'Class of all students' and (isEnrolledForSubject min 1 'Class of all subjects')

VeryActiveStudent = 'Class of all students' and (isEnrolledForSubject min 4 'Class of all subjects')
```

but I don't know how to define it for `InactiveStudent` - the condition is that such student has not enrolled for `ANY subject`. The thing is, that when I define an individual John I cannot make object property assertion on him saying "`isEnrolledForSubject null`", because Protege's wizard is expecting a individual from defined range.

How can one solve this kind of situation?

Comment: In addition to Henriette Harmse's answer: there are [negative object property assertions](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Negative_Object_Property_Assertions) in OWL2.

Comment: @StanislavKralin that won't help in this case. A negative object property assertion can state for example that individual `a` is not related to individual `b` via object property `r`. It cannot state that `a` is **not related to any** individual via object property `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define it as follows:

`InactiveStudent = 'Class of all students' and (isEnrolledForSubject max 0 'Class of all subjects')`

Then when you define a `inactiveStudent` individual, you will need to state it as follows:

```
inactiveStudent Type 'Class of all students'
inactiveStudent Type isEnrolledForSubject max 0 'Class of all subjects'
```

The reason for this is due to 2 factors:

(1) Object properties defines relations between 2 **individuals**. There is no way to state that an individual in **not** in a relation with any other individual besides by constraining its type as I did.

(2) If an individual is not linked to another individual via an object property, nothing more can be inferred due to the **open world assumption**.  Informally it means that the only inferences that the reasoner can make from an ontology is based on explicit information stated in the ontology or what can derived from explicit stated information.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm! I didn't even know I can use "Types" of individual this way.