# How do I get a Negative Object Property Assertion inferred?

Tags: ontology, protege, reasoning, swrl, object-properties

I am working in an ontology, and I have the following swrl rule:

```
User(?u) ^ Project(?p) ^ isRelatedTo(?u, ?p) ^ isMemberOf(?u, ?p) -> verifiedAssociation(?u, ?p)
```

And I would like to know when a Negative Object Property Assertion happens (when verifiedAssociation is not true).

I found on Protégé the tab Property Assertions, but I would like this to be inferred (by the reasoner). And I don't know how to create a rule to make this happen.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please check [FAQs on **Asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
Please format your post to make it more readable (Bold, italic, list , code indentation etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that inference through a rule. Reason being that what you need sort of is to be able to say that

```
User(?u) ^ Project(?p) ^ isNotRelatedTo(?u, ?p) ^ isNotMemberOf(?u, ?p) 
  -> unverifiedAssociation(?u, ?p)
```

but you need to say that `?u` is not related to **any** `?p`, not only as specific ?p. This falls outside to scope of rules and outside the scope of OWL/DLs because it requires a form of closed world reasoning rather open world reasoning.

To achieve your desired result you need to close your world in some way. So you have users that are either assigned to a project or they are not assigned as yet. Let us introduce `NoProject` class which is disjoint with `Project`. You then add a rule

```
User(?u) ^ NoProject(?p)
  -> unverifiedAssociation(?u, ?p)
```

where `unverifiedAssociation` is disjoint with `verifiedAssociation`.

You may also want to look at the [Individual with “null” object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463808/individual-with-null-object-property/49464155#49464155)
 Stack Overflow question.

**Update**

SWRL does not support negation according to the [SWRL FAQ](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLLanguageFAQ). The only way is to define duals of your object properties that are disjoint. I.e.,

```
ObjectProperty: isMemberOf
ObjectProperty: isNotMemberOf
    DisjointWith: isMemberOf
```

Do similar for `VerifiedAssociation` and `NotVerifiedAssociation`. Then you define your rule in a positive form:

```
User(?u) ^ Project(?p) ^ isRelatedTo(?u, ?p) ^ isNotMemberOf(?u, ?p) 
  -> NotVerifiedAssociation(?u, ?p)
```

Comment: But if I wanted to say:
User(?u) ^ Project(?p) ^ isRelatedTo(?u, ?p) ^ isNotMemberOf(?u, ?p) -> NotVerifiedAssociation(?u, ?p)

Meaning to say that a specific user doesn't have a verifiedAssociation to a specific project. It wouldn't be possible as well, right?

Obs: isRelatedTo and isMemberOf are both property chains with the same range and same domain, but with different paths (sub object properties). If one of them is not satisfied, then I want to say it is not verified/ not consistent.

Comment: SWRL does not support negation. See [SWRL FAQ](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLLanguageFAQ).

Comment: Updated answer to address your latest comment.