# Object Properties with disjoint classes in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege

I would like to model an ontology where I can represent an absence of entity so to say.
I want for example to have Rain and No_Rain, which I would define as disjoint classes.
After this I have the object Property has_rain.
I want somehow to be able to reason that it's not possible to have at the same time for the same individual has_rain(Rain) and has_rain(No_Rain)
I've searched a lot and couldn't find the answer to my problem. Maybe I've missed it somewhere. Sorry if I didn't explain everything good, this is my first question. I hope you understood everything and thanks in advance!
Edit:

```
<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#has_rain -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#has_rain">
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#No_Rain -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#No_Rain"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#Rain -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#Rain"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#Scene -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#Scene"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#no_rain -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#no_rain"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#rain -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#rain"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#scene -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#scene">
    <has_rain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#rain"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// General axioms
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDifferent"/>
    <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#no_rain"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/qala/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-28#rain"/>
    </owl:distinctMembers>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I also started using owlready, but I am still new there, but if I had to model this in code it would be :

```
with ontology:
class Rain(Thing):
    pass

class No_Rain(Thing):
    pass

class Scene(Thing):
    pass

class has_rain(ObjectProperty):
    domain = [Scene]
    range = [Rain or No_Rain]

rain = Rain("rain")
no_rain = No_Rain("no_rain")
AllDisjoint(Rain, No_Rain)
```

I hope this makes it more clear.

[class hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrBPv.png)

[object properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xggam.png)

[individuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMwQP.png)

[scene individual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MbRD.png)

Comment: Please provide code or at least diagram.

Comment: I have now added code and pictures, I hope this is enough. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to define scenes that can have different weather. Ideally a scene should not be able to have both snow and being dry.

Because this is about a scene, I will define different types of `SceneWeather`, i.e. `DryScene`, `SnowyScene` and `RainyScene`, which is disjoint from each other - it cannot snow and rain at the same time. Then I define object properties `hasRain` with `RainyScene` as domain and likewise `hasSnow` and `isDry`.

I have introduced `SceneWeather` as a parent class with the assumption that you likely will want to capture various scene related information. In the example below I included `SceneTimeOfDay` with `Morning` as subclass and `isMorning` as object property with `Morning` as domain.

Based on the above you can then define a `snowyMorningScene` by asserting that for `snowyMorningScene` we have `hasSnow` and `isMorning`. Using a reasoner it will infer that `snowyMorningScene` is of type `SnowyScene` and `Morning`. If you now state that `snowyMorningScene` `isDry`, it will result in an inconsistency.

Below is the complete ontology for doing this.

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:untitled-ontology-291="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isDry -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isDry">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneWeather"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#DryScene"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isMorning -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isMorning">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneTimeOfDay"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Morning"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isRainy -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isRainy">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneWeather"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#RainyScene"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isSnowy -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#isSnowy">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneWeather"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SnowyScene"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneTimeOfDay -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneTimeOfDay"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneWeather -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#sceneWeather"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#DryScene -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#DryScene">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneWeather"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#MidDay -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#MidDay">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneTimeOfDay"/>
        <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Morning"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Morning -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Morning">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneTimeOfDay"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#RainyScene -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#RainyScene">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneWeather"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Scene -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Scene"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneTimeOfDay -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneTimeOfDay">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Scene"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneWeather -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneWeather">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#Scene"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SnowyScene -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SnowyScene">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SceneWeather"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#dry -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#dry"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#morning -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#morning"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#snow -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#snow"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#snowyMorningScene -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#snowyMorningScene">
        <isDry rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#dry"/>
        <isMorning rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#morning"/>
        <isSnowy rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#snow"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // General axioms
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDisjointClasses"/>
        <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#DryScene"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#RainyScene"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henriette/ontologies/2021/1/untitled-ontology-291#SnowyScene"/>
        </owl:members>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your suggestion .Sorry I guess I haven't really made it clear what I exactly need. I want to be able to represent the absence of an entity. The Rainy Scene is there (Scene has_rain(Rain)), but I also want to be able to represent that the Scene doesn't have any Rain. 
I have problems with this since its Open World Assumption and the missing connection to has_rain isn't enough to know that the Scene doesn't have Rain.
The problem is that the Reasoner doesn't know when the instance is a no instance so to say, so it's not enough just to create no_rain or something of the type.

Comment: This is the reason why I tried to make them Disjoint, but the disjointness of classes only doesn't allow that one instance is part of both classes of the same time. And for further information I would like to use the "no" instances not only for rain, but also for example for no shoes, no t-shirt etc. So my problem is pretty general, how to represent those "no" instances. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I also though about using them in class expression in the individuals definition (anonymous definition) for example : 
has_rain exactly 0 Rain. But I am not sure that this is also the correct way to represent it, since it's not directly connected to the individual with object property

Comment: I have written about open world assumption [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2019/02/23/understanding-owl-min-vs-max-vs-exactly-property-restrictions/) and how you can deal with it. See [also](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/09/why-does-the-reasoner-ignore-my-constraint/).

Comment: You can also consider using SWRL. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046785/how-do-i-get-a-negative-object-property-assertion-inferred/50049080#50049080).

Comment: You can also consider using SHACL which is used for close world reasoning. See example [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/15/classification-with-shacl-rules/).

Comment: One last question, I am already familiar with SWRL rules and I want to use them.
I see in your example In productWithoutPrice that you have defined it as the class Product_With_max1Price and then said has_price max 0:xsd. 
Does it make sense to define in my case class SceneWithoutRain EquivalentTo Scene and has_rain max 0 Rain, in order to be able to use this class as Predicat in my SWRL rules? I also want to use EquivalentTo, so each scene individual with "has_rain max 0 Rain" gets connected to this Class and then it would work with the SWRL rules. Or should I use directly "Rules View"?

Comment: I see that the Rules View is more powerful, since I can use there also OWL Class Expressions, but I mostly see people use the SWRL Rules.
Also Thank you very much, this helps a lot ! I will check your other papers in your page for sure! (I didn't have spaces in the other comment )

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: This is actually wrong, to do it this way.

Okay actually I somehow managed to fix my problem :D If you define the object property as functional and then try to connect an individual with both rain and no_rain, then the reasoner tells you it's inconsistent, which was what I needed.
I would still be happy if someone says, if this is the correct way to model it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HubK3.png)

Comment: Using a functional restriction is the wrong way to do this. It fails for the wrong reason. That is it failed because you linked 2 individuals via has_Rain. It will fail even if you link it to `hasRain(Rain)` and `has_Rain(OtherRain)`.

Comment: I see what you mean and understand why. It doesn't fail when I put it with OtherRain, but it infers that they are the same individual and when I select that they are different, it gives an error.

Comment: Can you then maybe suggest me the correct way to do this? Or give me some hints? Thanks ! And also thank you for you answer before that.